# Oracle SQL Query - Replace ID by Name

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, self-join

I have a table `group` containing groups with their parent group:

```
groupid   name   parentid
-------------------------
   1      test       1 
   2      second     1
   3      3rd        1
   4      next       2
```

How can I query this table to receive a result like this (name instead id)

```
groupid   name     parent
---------------------------
   1      test     test
   2      second   test
   3      3rd      test
   4      next     second
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below Query:

```
select A.groupid, A.name, B.name as parentid
from group A
left join group B on A.groupid = B.parentid
```

Comment: Thank you! This works fine and now i can implement this to a bigger querie. Is the position ok? [`code`]select 
PPOM_USER.PUSER_ID,
PPOM_USER.PUSER_NAME,
PPOM_GROUP.PNAME,
p.PNAME
from PPOM_GROUP
full outer join ( PPOM_USER
full outer join PPOM_MEMBER
on
PPOM_USER.PUID = PPOM_MEMBER.RUSERU )
on
PPOM_GROUP.PUID = PPOM_MEMBER.RGROUPU
left join PPOM_GROUP p on p.PUID = PPOM_GROUP.RPARENTU[`/code`]

Answer (score 2):

That's a self-join:

```
select t.groupid, t.name, p.name parentname
from mytable t
inner join mytable p on p.groupid = t.parentid
```

If you have missing `parentid`s, then use a `left join` instead.

Comment: @ChristianTimm: are you aware that the answer you accepted is exactly the same as mine, and was posted 10 minutes later?